# java reflection unexpected noSuchMethodException

Tags: java

we're trying to invoke a method(java.lang.Math.max) by reflection.
But for some reason getDeclaredMethod throws NoSuchMethodException.
We think it can't be the fault of getDeclaredMethod() because the method never gets invoked.

Code:

```
private void executeMethod(Class cls, String methodName, Object[] params, Class[] paramTypes) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramTypes);

    try {
        m.invoke(null, params);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: MachineState]

```
Class methodClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Math");
String methodName = "max"; 
Object paramVals[] = new Object[2];
paramVals[0] = paramTypes[0].getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(8);
paramVals[1] = paramTypes[].getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(8);
paramTypes[0] = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");
paramTypes[1] = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        executeMethod( methodClass, methodName, paramVals, paramTypes);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) for `getDeclaredMethod`?

Comment: How are you calling `executeMethod`?  What are the exact arguments you're passing in?

Comment: edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the parameter types doesn't match.

`Math.max` has 4 overloads for `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`. All of them are primitive types. For example if you want to get the int overload, you need to use `int.class` instead of `Integer.class`, otherwise you get `NoSuchMethodException`, because the signature doesn't match.

```
executeMethod(Math.class, "max", 
              new Integer[]{1, 2}, // Cannot be int array, but we have auto unboxing.
              new Class[]{int.class, int.class});
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be an `Integer` array. It can be `Object[]`.

Comment: thanks for the solution, but we have to read the param types out of an xml file. How do we go about doing this?